# Azure App service - Diagnose and solve problem screen empty

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-appservice

In my app service behaves unusual, I am getting 502 errors for my request.

When I checked the logs, it didn't contain any errors.

Diagnose and solve problems are also displaying an empty screen.

[image]

The app service is very slow if click any options to load.

Comment: Please close the browser and try again

Comment: @MarkusMeyer I tried that, even I tried using incognito mode.

Comment: @Sathiamoorthy , can you try deleting the browser cache and check once or can you try opening in different browser

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MSFT, I tried different browsers and clearing the cache. Nothing works.